# AndroidManifest gets updated after prepare Cordova, missing lines

Tags: android, cordova

Have someone encountered problem when after prepare some data removes from AndroidManifest?

I add platform with android, when I prepare android platform, some values get lost from the AndroidManifest.

If i delete android.json and make prepare againg, it pulls the correct values.

Have someone been in touch with problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen such issue myself, but I would check installed plugin's plugin.xml files for 'after_platform_add' or 'before _platform_add' hooks scripts. and if one of the plugins is not altering AndroidManifest file in wrong way after/before platform add.